# Hover effect on li - applies to all of them

Tags: html, css

Couldn't think of a good way to word my question.

[Here is the design in question](http://www.animavivo.com/)

I want it so that the social media banners at the top right move down when you hover over each one of them. I'm using margin-top to do that and each banner is a list item.

When I hover over one of the images, all of the other ones drop down too!

My question is: how can I make it so that the one that the cursor on is the only one that moves down?

HTML:

```
<ul id="social-media">
        <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#social-media { 
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 80%;
    position: absolute;
}

#social-media li { display: inline-block; margin-top: -15px; }
#social-media li:hover { margin-top: 0; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the `li` elements. This ensures that the elements are aligned properly, otherwise it uses the baseline and produces the effect you see.

Comment: That worked! I feel silly for asking a question with such a simple answer. Would you mind explaining more in depth how that helped? Do you mean that it pushed the top down instead of the bottom down?

Comment: By default, `inline-block` elements will align to the baseline of their content. If you move one of them down, the others will follow the baseline. Setting `vertical-align:top` forces the elements to align according to the box itself, not its contents.